# how keep the integrity of data using websql

Tags: html, web-sql

I am Making a web app using websql and I'm leaning about websql but can't find anything about foreign key and some topics else, someone could give the feature of websql to know if is's possible o some tutorial to do this.

Comment: I believe that websql is implemented using sqlite for all databases. Have you tried using sqlite style foreign keys?

Comment: websql not support foreign key :(

Comment: You just need to take care to check the database for consistency on your own code.